# Allowing users to hide submissions in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, schema

I've got a site where users submit submissions and they all get displayed on the homepage.  I want to put a little button on each submission that says "hide"...If a user clicks this link they will no longer see the submission anywhere on the site.

Currently my index action for the submission is simply:

```
def index
  @submissions = Submission.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

My plan was to create a model hidden like so:

```
rails g model hidden user_id:integer submission_id:integer
```

Then, a hidden model instance gets created when the user hides something.  I would then have to update my controller to something like:

```
def index
  @submissions = Submission.order("created_at DESC").includes("hidden").where("hiddens.user_id IS NULL")
end
```

Though this obviously won't work.

Do I have a good database schema for this? What is the most efficient query I can do to make sure I don't display hidden submissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 3 tables:

1. Submission
2. Hidden
3. User

note you have many-to-many associations. Now whenever user clicks button to hide Submission, you create a row in table Hidden with proper submission_id and user_id. Then, in your controller, you can fetch all Submissions without ids that user marked as "hidden".

By the way: be aware that you should implement reverse from hiding (in case someone made a mistake or changed his mind0

Comment: this was my general plan. I guess the part I was most trying to figure out is the best way to do a query that searches all submissions that the user hasn't hidden.

Comment: @weckersham I would first find all submissions that user has hidden and then use it in the second query to take all submissions where ID is NOT in (result_from_previous_query). This of course can be done in one query with left outer join where hidden.submission_id is null. Not sure which approach would work better - a simple loop with  100 queries should give you the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something, I'd simply add a 'hidden' attribute to the Submission model (Boolean).

When the user clicks your "hide" link, you set the attribute to true.

Then you simply look for submissions with the flag set to false:

```
Submission.where(:hidden => false)
```

Comment: the problem here is it needs to be customized for each individual user.  If I just make it boolean on the submission model it will be hidden for everyone. Make sense?

Comment: yes, my bad. I thought the action of hiding was meant to be performed by the owner of the submission

Comment: my apologies! I'm sure I didn't explain it properly